# CSS3 appending content to pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

is it syntactically possible to add content to a before / after element.

Css:

```
.feature:before {
  content: "Feature ";
}


.bugfix:before {
  content: "Bugfix ";
}
```

Html:

```
<li class="feature bugfix">
   Some Info Text
</li>
```

This will result in a "Feature Some Info Text".
Or what is a better approach?

Comment: I doubt you can have two "Before" pseudo elements at once.

Comment: y and thats the question is it possible that i got both contents?

Comment: You example will result in "Bugfix Some Info Text" as the second declaration overrides the first one. http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3hfWM/

Comment: you cannot use 2 `:before`s , last one will overwrite the upper ones

Comment: correct thats the problem. And i was looking for a better / right solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to manipulate element content, I recommend Javascript instead of CSS. Javascript, like CSS, is evaluated by the user's browser so it lets you do things with the elements. Unlike CSS, JS is a scripting language and so it allows you to describe what you want programmatically.

For example, this is the JS code for what you did in the question:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('featured')[0];
var content = elem.innerHTML;
elem.innerHTML='Featured: '+content;
```

This is what you could do with javascript:

```
//This code checks if there are any content in the element
//and if not, politely says there are no featured elments
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('featured')[0];
var content = elem.innerHTML;
if(content)
{
    elem.innerHTML='Featured: '+content;
}
else
{
    elem.innerHTML='No featured items :(';
}
```

Here is some more informaton about javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

You can use jquery, which is a javascript library, along with JS to have more human readable (and writable) code.

This is an example of a jquery code for what you did in the question:

```
$('.featured').before('Featured: ');
```

This is an example of a jquery code for what you could do:

```
//This code puts an index in front of all the featured items.
$('.featured').each(function(index){
    $(this).prepend((index+1)+'.');
});
```

Also some information about jquery: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

On the other hand if you are seeking the ways of CSS for manipulating element content, having a new element-like structure right after or before the preferred element is as far as you get. You can style that structure like an element and all, but that's it.

You may be interested in further information on this topic too: http://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Edit:

If what you want is only to use two before sections at once with CSS, here is a workaround:

```
<style>
    .bugfix:before
    {
        content:'Bugfix! ';
    }
    .featured:before
    {
        content:'Featured: ';
    }
</style>
<div class="bugfix">
    <div class="featured">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/BY4ec/1/

Comment: Almost, my thinking was, that i can use css to tag them with more then one label. But it seems that it works only with JS.

Comment: I think what I added to the answer is simply what you wanted

Comment: I think there is nothing better then this :S but its still ugly mhh maybe in css4 there is something better :D

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible with `:before`.

Both your rules are styling **the same** `:before` element, so your second one overrides the first one (and actually you get "Bugfix Some Info Text").

I tried it and `something:before:before` does not work, unfortunately.

I think you will simply have to add some small spans into the markup to hold those "tags", pseudo-elements won't work for this.

Answer (score -1):

There's a mistake in value assignment.
Use `:` instead of `=`.

Then it's working.3

```
.feature:before {
   content:"Feature: "; // Instead of = use :
}


.bugfix:before {
   content:"Bugfix: ";
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqnV7/) but note you can't search for the word Bugfix on site because that content is not a selectable text.

Comment: sry yes. i din't mean ":" it is correct but was not the question :X

Answer (score -1):

You can also add some special characters to the content.

Here, look this up [Introduction to CSS escape sequences](http://www.merttol.com/articles/code/introduction-to-css-escape-sequences.html)

Comment: Yes but that was not asked at all.